# ansible json_query pasing CN name subject

Tags: ansible

I would like parsing DNS with json_query.
Here is example.

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "subject": "CN=DevTest22.aa.com,OU=IT Services,O=Deutsche,L=Berlin,ST=Nordrhein,C=DE",
            "version": 3
        },
        {
            "subject": "CN=Devops.aa.com,OU=IT Services,O=Deutsche,L=Berlin,ST=Nordrhein,C=DE",
            "version": 3
        },
        {
            "version": 3
        },
        {
            "subject": "CN=Devops22.aa.com,OU=IT Services,O=Deutsche,L=Berlin,ST=Nordrhein,C=DE",
            "version": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

I have create playbook which is work but for more data loop is too slow.

```
- name: search if  Common Name certificate exists in BIG-IQ 
  set_fact:
    CNs_exists: "{{ CNs_exists | d([])  + [ item ] }}"
  loop: "{{ json_file | json_query('items') }}"
  when: item.subject is defined and item.subject is search(CN_find)
  vars:
    CN_find: "CN=Devops22.aa.com"
```

problem is that subject are list and I need first value.

here is what I would like but this does not work

```
- name: search if  Common Name certificate exists in BIG-IQ
  set_fact:
    CNs_exists: "{{ CNs_exists | d([]) + [ item ] }}"
  loop: "{{  list_of_cert['json']['items'] | selectattr('subject') | selectattr('subject', '==', CN_find ) }}"
  vars:
    CN_find: "CN=Devops22.aa.com"
```

Comment: "this does not work" is not a useful description of the problem. I suspect that `selectattr('subject') | selectattr('subject', '==', CN_find )` should be `selectattr('subject', 'defined') | selectattr('subject', 'match', CN_find)` but it's impossible to say whether that actually addresses the error you see because you have not said what that error is.

Comment: For the record jQuery and `json_query`, which able you to do JMESPath queries are two totally different things.

Comment: thank you @flowerysong  your answer help me. This is what I am looking for.
      loop: "{{  json_file['items'] | selectattr('subject', 'defined') | selectattr('subject', 'search', CN_find ) }}"
      vars:
        CN_find: "CN=Devops22.aa.com"

Answer (score 0):

this code is what I am looking for.

```
- name: search if  Common Name certificate exists in BIG-IQ
  set_fact:
    CNs_exists: "{{ CNs_exists | d([]) + [ item ] }}"
  loop: "{{  json_file['items'] | selectattr('subject', 'defined') | selectattr('subject', 'search', CN_find ) }}"
  vars:
    CN_find: "CN=Devops22.aa.com"
```